# Conditional testing in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write query on a tables which query record based on some condition plus I need one column as status which should checking matching record on another table and set value based on that test.

For example, we have these two tables:

```
| USER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | CURR_STATUS |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1234567 | ABC        | DEF       | ACTIVE      |
| 8910111 | GHI        | JKL       | INACTIVE    |
| 2131415 | MNO        | PQR       | INACTIVE    |
| 1617181 | STU        | VWX       | ACTIVE      |
| 9202122 | YZA        | BCD       | ACTIVE      |
--------------------------------------------------
Table: USER

| USER_ID | DOC_NAME |
---------------------
| 1234567 | EFG.TXT  |
| 1617181 | HIJ.PDF  |
----------------------
Table: USER_DOC

> select first_name, last_name, curr_status
  //TODO some sql code for HAS_DOC logic
  from USER
  where CURR_STATUS = 'ACTIVE';

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | CURR_STATUS | HAS_DOC |
--------------------------------------------------
| ABC        | DEF       | ACTIVE      | YES     |
| STU        | VWX       | ACTIVE      | YES     |
| YZA        | BCD       | ACTIVE      | NO      |
--------------------------------------------------
Result
```

Right now I am doing this in Java code with two separate SQL calls:

1. First to get the all record matching record from USER table.
2. Then calling second query in the for loop

   ```
   select user_id from user_doc from user_id = :userId;
   ```

I am trying to see if it is can be done with single SQL query and it is faster.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the `EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.curr_status
FROM user u 
WHERE u.curr_status = 'ACTIVE'
AND EXISTS (SELECT d.doc_name FROM user_doc d WHERE d.user_id = u.user_id);
```

If you need more information (say, a document count), you may also try

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.curr_status, COUNT(d.doc_name) AS num_documents
FROM user u LEFT JOIN user_doc d ON d.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE u.curr_status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY u.first_name, u.last_name, u.curr_status
HAVING num_documents > 0;
```

One last alternative would be to use the `IN` operator

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.curr_status
FROM user u 
WHERE u.curr_status = 'ACTIVE'
AND u.user_id IN (SELECT d.user_id FROM user_doc d);
```

**EDIT** The "HAS_DOC" attribute can be derived from the count, for example

```
-- Gets all users

SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.curr_status, COUNT(d.doc_name) AS num_documents
FROM user u LEFT JOIN user_doc d ON d.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE u.curr_status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY u.first_name, u.last_name, u.curr_status;
```

and in your Java code:

```
boolean hasDoc = resultSet.getInt("num_documents") > 0;
```

Comment: I am not trying to limit the record I am trying to get HAS_DOC field value.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend something like this. (EDIT: tested, and it works)

```
select u1.first_name, u1.last_name, u1.curr_status,
       nvl2(u2.user_id, 'YES', 'NO') as has_doc
  from USER u1
  left join (select u.user_id
             from USER u
             where u.CURR_STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
             and exists (
                select null
                from user_doc ud
                where ud.user_id = u.user_id)
             ) u2 ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id
  where u1.CURR_STATUS = 'ACTIVE';
```

Comment: You can do it shorter and faster as shown in the other answers. I won't recommend using this approach.

Comment: @Luigi: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if users can potentially have many associated documents, won't my query run faster because it doesn't need to iterate every single `user_doc` record?

Comment: I recommend executing a query plan on your query and @Dirk's query to see the performance of both queries by yourself.